# Label in a UITableViewCell, change second line font size, add margins?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview that uses UITableViewCell and is populated by data from parse.com. In the UITableViewCell there is a LABEL that has 2 lines, that shows data from parse.com.

I am wondering if it is possible to change the font size of the second line of the LABEL (leave the first line's font size the same), also is there is there a way to add margins to the left and right of the label?

EDIT: mistyped, i want to change the font size of the second line of a LABEL, as well as add margins to the left and right of the label.

Comment: A single label with two fonts will required the use of `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: How do I do it for line 2? I found a way to make a range of cjaracters change got buy not line.is there a way to set the last chatacters

Comment: I am not aware of any way to use `NSAttributedString` per line. You can use `\n` to put a line break where you want it and use `NSAttributedString` with a range. You will know the range based on where the line break was placed.

Answer (score 1):

In my solution I have made an used the `attributedText` of the `UILabel` to add attributed string to the label

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"My first line \n")
//creating NSMutableAttributedString that will be later appended with your second line

var secondLine = "My attributed second line"
let secondLineAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 22)!]
//replace 22 with the size of text you want for second line
var newAttributedSecondLine: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: secondLine, attributes: secondLineAttribute)
attributedString.appendAttributedString(newAttributedSecondLine)

label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Dont forget to add `label.numberOfLines=2` before the above code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Book", size: 16)
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: i only want to change the font of the second line

Comment: @gooberboobbutt you need to add seprate label

Comment: ya i think thats the best solution

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell has two labels `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` if created with `Subtitle` style. Configure `detailTextLabel` as you like. Otherwise make your own UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: I dont think that's going to work for me but, the code for the label is self.singlevoteresult1.append("\(votes!)      \n(\(vote1percentage)%)                . " as String). How come the spaces at the end (after vote1percentage%)  don't show? is there anyway i can make it so it shows, that would fix my problem, i know a little ghetto. EDIT: it isnt showing but i have 5 spaces after it.